# using python compare 2 columns, find maximum value from 3rd column for same values of col1 & col2 and output it as a new 3rd column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
Theta Phi EIRP
  0  -180  4.76
  0  -180  -19.62
 15  -180  3.76
 15  -180  2.23
 15  -180  3.89
 15  -165  2.93
 15  -165  5.807
 15  -150  3.95
 15  -150  2.95
 15  -150  -0.88
..    ...  ...
..   ...   ...
..   ...    ...
```

theta varies from 0 to 180 degrees
phi varies from -180 to 180 degrees
EIRP can be any value

all 3 columns will have equal number of rows (500+ values)

expected output is

```
Theta Phi Max.EIRP
  0  -180  4.76
 15  -180  3.89
 15  -165  5.807
 15  -150  3.95
...   ...   ...
...   ...   ...
...   ...   ...
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Theta','Phi']).max().reset_index()`.

Comment: the code does not work. i m very new to python. please put detailed code. thanks a lot.

Comment: @QuangHoang please put detailed quote. i m new to python. thanks